# Tiff tag data buffer strange hex values for floating point variables

Tags: binary, hex, byte, buffer, tiff

So, I have been assigned a task to read and save values of C-struct that was stored within tifftag of tiff image as byte buffer. This might be quite simple, but I am quite new to this realm of programming.

I know the exact positions I need to read bytes from. When I use python tiff tag readers, I get these weird values of bytes, that I could not make sense of. I was expecting it to be `\xb5\x00\x00\x00\x01`
format, not something strange like `\n\xd7#=\n\xd7#=K`.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3xiY.png) is the snippet of weird buffer values

However, in utility app **AsTiffViewer**, those are perfectly fine as shown
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCvIz.png)

How do I decode this? What does this all mean?

```
\n\xd7#=\n\xd7#=K (0A D7 23 3D 0A D7 23 3D - as per AsTiffViewer)
```

By the way, these `0A D7 23 3D` & `0A D7 23 3D` are supposed to be two float value, each of them 4 bytes.

I was expecting tiff tag byte buffer to be in format of`\xb5\x00\x00\x00\x01` etc, However, it spit out some weird format - `\n\xd7#=\n\xd7#=K`. I don't know how to decode or read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after mucking around a bit, I found out that, `\n\xd7#=\n\xd7#=K`, this is nothing but how python represents float in binary string.